# Limits and Minimum Value

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need your help with this question:

Suppose $ f:(0,1) \rightarrow \Bbb{R} $ is a continuous function such that:

$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty $ and $ \lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = +\infty $

Prove that $f$ has a minimum value in $ (0,1) $

So my first thought was to "decode" what I am given:

$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty $ means that for every $M>0$ there exists a $δ_1>0$ such as for every $x$ in $(0,1)$: $\vert{x}\vert < δ_1 \implies f(x)>M$

$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = +\infty $ means that for every $M'>0$ there exists a $δ_2>0$ such as for every $x$ in $(0,1)$: $\vert{x-1}\vert < δ_2 \implies f(x)>M'$

From here I do not know how to combine those to get the result
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: A continuous function is bounded except possibly at its endpoints, right? If it has no minimum then it must approach $-\infty$ and by hypothesis, not at either endpoint. So it must be unbounded at some point within the interval. This contradicts continuity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $M>f(1/2)$. Take $\delta \in (0,1/4)$ s.t. $f(x)>M$ whenever $0<x<\delta $ and $1-\delta <x<1 $. Since $[\delta ,1-\delta ]$ is compact, $f$ will take its minimum on $[\delta ,1-\delta ]$ which will be a global minimum.